# Passing Data Between ASP.net Pages using vb.net

Tags: asp.net

I am writing *my very first* asp.net application and am trying to use the PreviousPage property to access data between pages.  Visual 2010 is giving me an error which I don't understand, so I need some help to understand what I am doing wrong.

I have an application where I will bounce between all the pages using Transfer.  That way, from a user perspective there is only ever one url that he sees. This url will be the one that makes him log in to the application (a application controlled function for now) and connect to the database.  I therefore have an sqlclient.sqlconnection object that I wish to hand off to the next page called _dbConnection  this is a private variable in my page class declared ...

```
   Partial Class Protocol
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Private _dbconnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Public ReadOnly Property dbConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection
            Get
                Return _dbConnection
            End Get
        End Property
        ...
```

Later down the code, in reponse to a click event on a button

```
Server.Transfer("PSetup.aspx")
```

In PSetup.aspx I have the following

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeFile="PSetup.aspx.vb" Inherits="PSetup" %>
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Protocol.aspx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
```

Which should declare the Protocol class as the previous page

However in PSetup's Page_Load Sub I attempt this

```
_dbConnection = PreviousPage.dbConnection
```

where in this use _dbConnection is a private variable in the new page class.

Visual Studio is giving me an error 'dbConnection' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Page'

I have read through the documentation about this several times and I just don't understand what I am doing wrong.  Could someone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the first thing you need to understand is that ASP.NET is stateless.  That means that no data is "saved" between pages.  What the `PreviousPage` property does is it allows the request information persist through the use of a `Transfer` method, and the request information will be the GET or POST variables.

IMHO, the best way to do what you desire, is to have a shared public class that is not related to either page, and have a public function for getting the `SqlConnection`.  Remember though, it is stateless, so you will have to create the connection each time.

Another alternative would be to save the dbConnection in the session (which I don't recommend, since it is possible to view the session information).

Otherwise, you can't have a variable persist with information between pages.  Thats what is means to be stateless.

ALSO, for `PreviousPage`, keep in mind that it is creating an instance of `System.Web.UI.Page`, not an instance of `Protocol`.  That means public properties won't exist from `Protocol`, only native features of `Page` will be there.

**edit**

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

Note

Properties on the source page that are created primarily to expose values for cross-page posting are usually read-only properties. Although the source page can contain public read/write properties, setting a source page property from the target page property generally has no purpose, because the value will not be persisted.

Comment: From my (primarily) linux/apache/php background I understand stateless.  However asp.net certainly gives the impression that the page object exists between requests - all the private variables in the (instance of the) page class seems to maintain state whilst there are round trips to and from the client as a result of events on the page. Microsoft examples talk about PreviousPage being strongly typed to the actual page, and then to proceed to give an example of "CurrentCity" as a property that can be retrieved.  What I don't see is how my example is different.

Comment: Hey, that definitely is my mistake!  When `<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %> ` is added (as you have done) it does for it to be strongly typed (otherwise, it is done using the Page.PreviousPage property, it is typed as Page).  But, I found that example, and it works because `CurrentCity` is a public property that returns the value of a text box, which is persisted through the request information.  It wouldn't return an arbitrary string that is set in the page load for the previous page, for example.

Comment: The page remembers the state of the controls because they are stored in the ViewState. I think in your case you could save the sqlConnection in the session, however its not good practice to do that.

Comment: I guess I will recreate the connection from its connection string every page - I can use session variables for the other stuff I need (there are just a few integers and strings).  Thanks for your help (both of you)

Comment: Further to previous statements, there is a little Gotcha.  For pages that might have several sources you can't use the @ PreviousPageType directive.  So I thought, just create hidden input fields and access them with PreviousPage.FindControl("id-of-hidden-field").  This didn't work because of MasterPages.  Instead you have to use findcontrol to get the ContentPlaceHolder and then use FindControl on the ContentPlaceHolder to get the field.

Answer (score 0):

try to make the dbConnection variable as Shared

```
Partial Class Protocol
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private Shared _dbconnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property dbConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Get
            Return _dbConnection
        End Get
    End Property
```

But I'm not sure if it is a good practice passing data between pages that way

Comment: Microsoft examples don't do shared - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx.  I would worry that shared was dangerous - wouldn't shared mean different users of the page all share the same connection? (in this case it might not matter - but I have other values that are definitely per user that I wish to pass between pages - this was just the first example - I am porting a windows form application that did it a similar way)

Comment: why don't you pass a data through a querystring or through the Session?